# SQL Update same field using a different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can one update the same field's value using a different ID?

```
Customer     ORderType
Matt            1
Jake            2
```

For all "Matt"s I want to set the orderType to 2 from Jake.

This doesnt work.

```
declare @X nvarchar (250)
set @x = (select OrderType from table where Customer = 'Matt')

update table
set OrderType = @x
where Customer = 'Jake'
```

Comment: Can you give the table definition for `table` ? What is the value of `@x` after the `SELECT` statement ? This query should basically work unless `@x` is NULL or if you are using `NVARCHAR` for the definition of `Customer`.

Comment: Which dbms? (You are using non ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Your query should work fine, just add a "top 1" when selecting the OrderType like so: set @x = (select top 1 OrderType from table where Customer = 'Matt')
Or include it as sub query as in my answer below

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, Top 1 isn't guaranteed to return you a single row. If two rows are ranked the same according to your sort criteria, SQL Server will give you both of them, even if you only ask for the Top 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a FROM clause in an UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE C SET OrderType = J.OrderType
FROM [Table] C
   CROSS JOIN [Table] J
WHERE C.Customer = 'Matt' AND J.Customer = 'Jake'
```

If you use a subquery instead, that subquery must return precisely one row.

Note also that your quoted line:

```
set @x = (select OrderType from table where Customer = 'Matt')
```

Can also be written as:

```
SELECT @x = OrderType FROM Table WHERE Customer = 'Matt'
```

People tend to overuse subqueries.

Comment: Use explicit joins. it's the standard for over 20 years now.

Comment: These tables are not joined on a matching field, which is why I didn't join them. The join would look something like this: FROM Table M JOIN Table J ON M.Customer = 'Matt' AND J.Customer = 'Jake'   Which isn't really a join at all

Comment: I believe It's a [cross join,](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table
set OrderType = (select TOP 1 OrderType from table where Customer = 'Matt')
where Customer = 'Jake'
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
update table
set OrderType = (select top 1 OrderType from table where Customer = 'Matt')
where Customer = 'Jake'
```